# Azure Devops release pipeline. Terraform plan fails

Tags: azure-devops, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I am working with Azure Devops release pipeline where I need to pass arguments for couple of variables. Pipeline is successfully executing terraform init, validate commands but it is giving error while executing terraform plan.

```
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.3/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
```

Need help on this.

Comment: Can you give more detail how you `terraform plan` looks? If this is release pipeline, can you add screenshot?

Comment: There are tasks mentioned in pipeline terraform init, terraform validate, terraform plan. When it comes to terraform plan execution with in seconds its giving the error below. 2020-05-21T06:58:38.5415099Z ##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/0.12.3/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1

Comment: Could you show the terraform code?

Comment: Normally the error log should be longer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was solved by removing these 2 arguments from the commandOptions: `-compact-warnings -input=false`.